# How to properly pass dash parameters to subprocessPopen

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
subprocess.Popen( ["-c", "kill -SIGUSR2 %s" % master],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).wait()
```

I'm getting

```
kill: 1: Illegal option -S
```

which refers to `-SIGUSR2`.

What would I do for that parameter to be passed completely as `-SIGUSR2`?

PS:

If I use `-s SIGUSR2` I'm getting `kill: 1: invalid signal number or name: SIGUSR2`

PPS:

If I use `["-c", "kill", "-SIGUSR2", master]` I'm getting

```
kill: 1: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are passing the wrong arguments to kill. Try passing -s SIGUSR2 instead

Comment: @Antimony: sorry I didn't put it originally. It doesn't work as well

Comment: Can you run kill with those arguments directly?

Comment: @Antimony: yep. Both `-SIGUSR2` and `-s SIGUSR2` run fine in terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIG` is implied.

You want `-USR2` instead:

```
subprocess.Popen( ["-c", "kill -USR2 %s" % master],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).wait()
```

GNU `coreutils`'`kill` can give you this list itself.

```
$ /bin/kill --list|grep USR2
USR2
```

---

EDIT: My mistake.  Your example is using the shell's `kill` and not GNU's.  You didn't say which shell, but based on the results, it's likely `dash` and not `bash`.  `bash` would allow you to use either `-SIGUSR2` or `-USR2`, but `dash` does not.

```
$ dash -c 'kill -l' |grep USR
USR1
USR2
$ bash -c 'kill -l' |grep USR
 6) SIGABRT  7) SIGBUS   8) SIGFPE   9) SIGKILL 10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGUSR2 13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM
$ bash -c 'kill -SIGUSR2 99999'
bash: line 0: kill: (99999) - No such process
$ bash -c 'kill -USR2 99999'
bash: line 0: kill: (99999) - No such process
$ bash -c 'kill -NOTASIGSPEC 99999'
bash: line 0: kill: NOTASIGSPEC: invalid signal specification
$ dash -c 'kill -SIGUSR2 99999'
dash: 1: kill: Illegal option -S
$ dash -c 'kill -USR2 99999'
dash: 1: kill: No such process
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know `dash` exists :-S

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["-c", "kill -USR2 %s" % master], 
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).wait()
```

However, SIGUSR2 is not a valid sigspec.  Perhaps [Brian Cain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489590/brian-cain) is correct, but I see examples including the SIG.

Comment: "However, SIGUSR2 is not a valid sigspec." --- well, I don't have choice - that's what a tool expects to receive

Comment: Well, seems like you guys are right. However `["-c", "kill", "-s", "-USR2", master]` form doesn't work (throwing the same message as in PPS), while `["-c", "kill -USR2 %s" % master]` does

Answer (score 1):

For me this works fine:

```
subprocess.Popen( ["-c", "kill -USR2 %s" % master],
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).wait()
```